# Extract String From String in PHP

Tags: php

I have string variable like **ABC/DF/G** I want extract DF from it means text between two /.
I have tried like below

```
$string= "ABC/DF/G";
$code = substr($string ,strpos($string,'/'));
echo $code;
```

but I am getting result like below

```
/DF/G
```

Let me know if someone can help me for do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` function to split a string into an array.

```
$string= "ABC/DF/G";
$code = explode('/', $string);
echo $code[1];
```